# How to retrieve all associated company RICs for a specified exchange RIC using the Refinitiv Eikon API?

Tags: python, thomson-reuters-eikon, refinitiv-eikon, refinitiv-eikon-api

Using the Refinitiv (formerly known as Thomson Reuters ) Eikon Data API, does anyone know how to quickly return all associated company RICs for exchanges such as Oslo Stock Exchange?

The RIC for Oslo Stock Exchange seems to be `.OSEBX`

And `eikon.get_data` has a few examples in the docstring:

```
import eikon as ek
ek.set_app_key('set your app key here')
data, err = ek.get_data(["IBM", "GOOG.O", "MSFT.O"], ["TR.PriceClose", "TR.Volume", "TR.PriceLow"])
data, err = ek.get_data("IBM", ['TR.Employees', {'TR.GrossProfit':{'params':{'Scale': 6, 'Curn': 'EUR'},'sort_dir':'asc'}}])
fields = [ek.TR_Field('tr.revenue'),ek.TR_Field('tr.open',None,'asc',1),ek.TR_Field('TR.GrossProfit',{'Scale': 6, 'Curn': 'EUR'},'asc',0)]
data, err = ek.get_data(["IBM","MSFT.O"],fields)
```

So I've tried different variations with `eikon.get_data(instruments = ".OSEBX", fields = "RIC")`, but with no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chain` (which always starts with `0#`), like this:

```
data, err = ek.get_data('0#.OSEBX', 'TR.CommonName')
```

This will give you the RICs of all the companies in the index, plus their respective company names.

Answer (score 2):

`0#.OSEBX` is an index that represents all shares traded on the market, so what you are really doing is requesting index constituents.

A better way is to execute an Equity Screener query. For example, this will return all stocks listed on OSE and Oslo Axess:

```
screener_exp ='SCREEN(U(IN(Equity(active,public,primary))), IN(TR.ExchangeMarketIdCode, XOAS, XOSL))'

df, e = ek.get_data(screener_exp, 'TR.CompanyName')
```

You can build screener queries with Eikon Excel.